# Setting value of numpy array based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to set the values in a numpy array to zero if it is equivalent to any number in a list.

Lets consider the following array

```
  a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
```

I want to set multiple elements of `a` which are in the list `[1, 2, 8]` to `0`.

The result should be

```
   [[0, 0, 3],
    [4, 0, 6],
    [7, 0, 9]]
```

For a single element it's simple

```
   a[a == 1] = 0
```

The above only works for a single integer.  How it could work for a list?

Comment: I feel like this should be doable using `numpy.where`. However, the intuitive choice of `numpy.where(a in [1,2,8], 0, a)` gives a `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. Maybe a more expert user could get it to work.

Comment: Just on a side note, you may already be aware of this, but if you only have  2-3 values, you just need to combine them with the `|` operator (`or` won't work).  e.g. `a[(a == 1) | (a == 2) | (a == 8)] = 0`  A common gotcha in numpy is trying to combine boolean arrays with `and`,`or`,`not` instead of `&`,`|`,`~`.  The former operators will raise an error if an array is passed in, but the latter operate element-wise. Of course, this is a bad approach for testing against multiple values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `np.in1d` you could do the following:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
>>> np.in1d(a, [1, 2, 8])
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> a[np.in1d(a, [1, 2, 8]).reshape(a.shape)] = 0
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 3],
       [4, 0, 6],
       [7, 0, 9]])
```

Comment: this is definitely the most computationally efficient, `np.vectorize` essentially is just syntactic sugar for a python `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

Combining my comment to the original question regarding `np.where` and the excellent answer by @Jaime above using `np.in1d`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
a = np.where(np.in1d(a, [1,2,8]).reshape(a.shape), 0, a)
```

**EDIT**
Looks like Jaime's solution is slightly faster:

```
In [3]: %timeit a[np.in1d(a, [1, 2, 8]).reshape(a.shape)] = 0
10000 loops, best of 3: 45.8 µs per loop
In [4]: %timeit np.where(np.in1d(a, [1,2,8]).reshape(a.shape), 0, a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 66.7 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own vectorized functions using `numpy.vectorize`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

def is_target_number(x):
    if x in set([1,2,8]):
        return True
    else:
        return False

f = np.vectorize(is_target_number)

a[f(a)] = 0
```

A lot of operators like the equality operator are already vectorized by default, `numpy.vectorize` allows you to use more complicated logic with the same benefit of succinctness. And if you're into code golf you can do something like this:

```
a[np.vectorize(lambda x: (x in set([1,2,8])))(a)] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
>>> lst = [1, 2, 8]
>>> a[numpy.vectorize(lambda x: x in lst)(a)] = 0
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 3],
       [4, 0, 6],
       [7, 0, 9]])
>>>
```

Comment: woah you beat me to the lambda thing by 10 seconds.. :)

Comment: @qwwqwwq - It actually looks like 13. ;)